# DRF mixin uses the model manager's create method but not the update method

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

```
# models.py
class HelloManager(models.Manager):
'''
On create, set date_created and last_modified to the same values
On update, set last_modified to current time
'''
def create(self, *args, **kwargs):
    current_time = datetime.now()
    kwargs.setdefault('date_created', current_time)
    kwargs.setdefault('last_modified', current_time)
    return super().create(*args, **kwargs)

def update(self, *args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['last_modified'] = datetime.now()
    return super().update(*args, **kwargs)
```

The `CreateModelMixin` works just fine, but the `UpdateModelMixin` does not call my manager's update method.

I went through DRF's implementation and found that the UpdateModelMixin calls `serializer.save()` which calls either `update` or `create` but this is where I got lost.

I tried just directly overriding `perform_create` like so:

```
# views.py
class HelloDetailView(mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                      mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                      generics.GenericAPIView):

queryset = HelloModel.objects.all()
lookup_field = 'id'

def get_serializer_class(self):
    if self.request.method == 'POST':
        return HelloWriteSerializer
    return HelloReadSerializer

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.retrieve(request, *args, **kwargs)

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return self.update(request, *args, **kwargs)

def perform_update(self, serializer):
    HelloModel.objects.update(**serializer.validated_data)
```

But the problem now is the `UpdateModelMixin` now returns old data. What's the best approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not passing **PK** or **ID** in the update method like this:

```
def perform_update(self, serializer):
    instance = serializer.instance
    HelloModel.objects.update(pk=instance.pk, serializer.validated_data)
```

Comment: serializer.validated_data already has an `id` field